# Limit of $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n}}{1+\sqrt{x_n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

By elementary methods, how does one find the limit of this sequence?

$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n}}{1+\sqrt{x_n}}$

Comment: If $x_{0}>0$, then by induction you will see that $x_{n}>0$, so $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n}}<1$, the sequence is strictly decreasing with lower bound, so it has limit, say, $L$, then $L=\dfrac{L}{1+\sqrt{L}}$, $L=0$ is the only solution. If $x_{0}=0$, it is the zero's sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trivial to prove that $x_n\ge 0$. Moreover:

$x_n-x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n}{1+\sqrt{x_n}}=x_n\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x_n}}\right)=x_n\frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{1+\sqrt{x_n}}\ge 0$

So $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ so it is convergent $x_n\rightarrow l$

By taking the limit on both sides of initial recurrence we get $l=\frac{l}{1+\sqrt{l}}$ which has as unique solution $l=0$

Comment: Note: the solution in the comments using the ratio is also good. +1

Comment: I would add that the series converges to $0$ at the rate of $n^{-2}$.